# Finding Running Standard Deviation for Values in Pandas DataFrame with Binned Values

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, astronomy

I have a DataFrame `limitdf` which has values binned in 31 bins, labeled in the column `MASS_BINS`. I would like to find the mean and standard deviation of other columns in this DataFrame for objects by bin. I tried to produce an array of tuples `(mean , std)` for each bin:

```
stdarray = []
for i in range(0 , 31):
    stdarray[i] = [(limitdf['td_lmass'][limitdf.MASS_BINS == i].mean(axis = 0) , limitdf['PAB_SFR_EX2'][limitdf.MASS_BINS == i].std(axis = 0))]
```

This yells at me with `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`. Why does this not work, or is there a better and easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this isn't a pandas issue, but actually to do with you attempting to assign a value to index `i` in `stdarray`, when `stdarray` is a list of length 0.

In simple language if `i`=0, what you're saying to python is "please replace element 0 of `stdarray` with x". But there is no element 0 for `stdarray` so python is crashing.

Because you are attempting to `assign` something to a `list index` that is `out of range`.

To fix your issue, you should try `stdarray.append(YOUR_CODE_HERE)` instead of `stdarray[i] = YOUR_CODE_HERE`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pandas' `DataFrame.rolling`? Take a look at [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html).